# What happens under the hood when a network request is made by an application

Tags: networking, system, data-monitoring

I'm interested in knowing what happens at the kernel level when an application makes a network request. While playing with `strace` I was hoping to find system calls like `connect()` to make a connection with an IP socket but instead, I found connections to local Unix sockets. From what I understand these connections may be for logging or any other system service. A lot of `ioctl` calls were also made which I'm guessing were for binder communication. 
If the application is not servicing the request, is it being passed on to a system service using IPC which then sends back the response to the application? I was wondering if these requests could be captured at the system level using `ptrace` in order to monitor/block them.
I'm using a rooted device running Android 7.1.2